# Normal map baking - All clean blue (no color variation)

Tags: uv, normals, texture-baking

I'm trying to bake a normal map from a high poly mesh, and apply on a low poly mesh (in Unreal Engine 4). Bare with me as I'm new to Blender, and especially new to normal map baking with Blender.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this task. The guides I've seen and read, explain how to uv unwrap the low poly mesh -> select the high poly -> shift-select the low poly -> hit bake (normal -> "Selected Active").

For some reason, everything shows up completely blue (no color variation -> No elevation information), and I'm not sure how to accomplish the baking?

**The UV of the low poly:**

[image]

**Normal Map:**

[image]

**Low poly VS. High poly:**

[image]

Could anyone help me?

**EDIT:**

Of course I'm aligning the 2 meshes so Blender can read the elevation differences.

Comment: Normal maps are not showing elevation of the faces, only normals angle, in your case all the normals facing low poly model exactly at the same angle, thats why you do not see any changes on the normal map

Comment: @Denis I'm afraid that I'm gonna need you to explain further. I'm not sure I understand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normal maps are not showing elevation of the faces, only normals angle (faces angle of high poly relative to low poly model), in your case all the normals facing low poly model exactly at the same angle, thats why you do not see any changes on the normal map.

In an example below you can see that faces that are 90 degrees to low poly model are not visible.

[image]

Comment: Ah okay I understand now. Thank you for clarification.